# How do I create a validator for a single collection?

Tags: kinto

I need to build a custom id validator that will apply to a single collection, whose id will always be pre-defined (won't need a generator).

In the [docs](http://kinto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom-id-generator.html) about id generators, it's written:

> Currently the configuration of the custom generator applies to every resources (buckets, groups, collections, records). This tiny limitation can easily be fixed, don’t hesitate to get in touch with us!

But there is nothing documented about id validation.

So, how do I:

1. Implement an  id *validator*, that
2. Will apply to one collection only?

Answer (score 0):

By default [cliquet uses a generator](https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/blob/master/cliquet/storage/generators.py#L7-L40) which accepts the following regular expression `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$'` (All letters and numbers + underscore and "-").

Before you chose to have a different ID validation mechanism, ensure you really need to.

Now, if that's not enough, you would need to select the proper validator depending on some configuration or already existing values, but this is not implemented in cliquet / kinto.

[https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/blob/master/cliquet/resource/**init**.py#L147](https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/blob/master/cliquet/resource/__init__.py#L147) is probably a good place to look at / start with.

Comment: I was using Kinto.js and it refused me to create an object using a non UUID4 formatted string. This seems to be imposed by Kinto.js (not kinto-server) as one can infer from your answer. Changing the id validation schema *solely* on Kinto.js did the trick. For posterity: http://kintojs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#custom-id-generation-using-an-id-schema.

Comment: Actually, what I said in the last comment is only partially true: you can make Kinto.js accept a non UUID4 id, but when you `.sync()`, you get an `path: Invalid id` error, meaning `kinto-server` still wants UUID4. Just to provide a way out to future readers, the tutorial in the docs (http://kinto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom-id-generator.html?highlight=id%20generator) is good if you are OK with editing id generation/validation globally. I still don't understand how to change it on a per-collection basis.

Comment: This restriction have been removed in Kinto 3.2